# Why FFT algorithm (Cooley-Tukey) takes O(nlogn)?

Tags: proof-writing, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, proof-explanation, fast-fourier-transform

I was wondering how this algorithm can be formally interpreted with an upper bound n*log(n). There's some formal proof for this? I would appreciate if somebody can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Is Master theorem involved?

Comment: check my answer to a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704788/complexity-of-fft-algorithms-cooley-tukey-bluestein-prime-factor