# Complexity of FFT algorithms (Cooley-Tukey, Bluestein, Prime-factor)

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I need to be able to explain the complexity of three Fast Fourier Transform algorithms: Cooley-Tukey's, Bluestein's and Prime-factor algorithm.

Unfortunatelly, I'm a little lost in the process.

---

### Discrete Fourier Transform general formula

\begin{align}
x &= \{x_0, ... , x_{N-1}\}\\
0 &\leq n \leq N-1 \\
X_n &= \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}x_k \cdot e^{\frac{-i\cdot 2\pi \cdot k \cdot n}{N}}
\end{align}

Here's the complexity pretty clear (at least I think :-) ):

1. We have a fixed number of multiplications and one division in the sum $\Rightarrow$ complexity of the sum content is $$O(1)$$
2. The sum itself contains a *loop from 0 to N-1*, so the loop runs N-times $\Rightarrow$ the complexity of the whole sum is $$O(N) \cdot O(1) = O(N)$$
3. And now, we have this sum for every *n* $\Rightarrow$ the sum will be "executed" N-times (the size of n is N) $\Rightarrow$ The complexity is $$O(N) \cdot O(N) = O (N^2)$$

---

### Cooley-Tukey's algorithm

The point is in dividing the sum according to the [Danielson-Lanczos lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Danielson-LanczosLemma.html):
$$
X_n = \sum^{\frac{N}{2}-1}_{k=0} x_{2n} \cdot e^{\frac{-i\cdot 2\pi \cdot k \cdot n}{\frac{N}{2}}} + e^{\frac{-i \cdot 2\pi \cdot n}{N}}\sum^{\frac{N}{2}-1}_{k=0} x_{2n+1} \cdot e^{\frac{-i\cdot 2\pi \cdot k \cdot n}{\frac{N}{2}}}
$$

Every sum can be recursively divided $log_2(N)$ times:

```
              N
       N/2        N/2
    N/4   N/4  N/4   N/4
             ...
   1         ...        1
```

1. Every sum has $O(1)$ complexity as above, so the only thing that matters is the number of iterations: $O(N), O(2\cdot \frac{N}{2}), O(4 \cdot \frac{N}{4})$... So, every step has the complexity $$O(N)$$.
2. We have $log_2(N)$ steps, so the complexity of $X_N$ will be
   $$O(N \cdot log N)$$
3. But still, this is the result just for one $X_n \Rightarrow$ **Why is not the complexity multiplied by 'n' again?** (as in the step 3 in the general DFT) **Or is there a mistake in previous steps?**

---

### Bluestein's algorithm

The point is here in rewriting the formula to the "special" shape, where the sum is the convolution of two sequences.

[image]

1. The multiplication of the sum and the exponential before it has a constant complexity $$O(1)$$
2. Because the sum is the convolution, we can use [the convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), so we must compute Fourier transforms for both sequences (which can need to be padded with zeros) and multiply them. Multiplication and zero padding are $O(1)$, Fourier transforms can be again $O(N \cdot log N)$ (we'll use Cooley-Tukey for them), so the complexity is 
   $$
   2 \cdot O(N \cdot log N) + O(1) = O(N \cdot log N)
   $$
3. And again - this is just for one $X_n$ - **Why shouldn't I multiply the complexity by O(N) for every 'n'?**

---

### Prime-factor algorithm

[image]

And here I have simply no idea how should I compute the complexity... I'd say that two nested sums are like two loops, so $O(N^2)$, but it's obviously wrong...

Comment: The complexity of the algorithms becomes *much* easier to determine when written in pseudocode. I think your questions about an extra linear factor would be clarified by starting from scratch with a reference implementation and giving a standard analysis.

Comment: @portin.daniel Ok, is there ANY way to determine it just from these mathematical formulas? I have literally zero previous experience and so I'm little anxious about making a mistake while rewriting them to presudocode :-)

Comment: For example, the Cooley-Tukey algorithm recursively divides a problem of size $n$ into two problems of size $n / 2$ and combines the results of solving those problems in $\Theta(n)$ time. Here, the size of the problem is the length of the input vector. If $n$ is a power of two, then $T(n) = 2T(n / 2) + \Theta(n)$ and $T(1) = \Theta(1)$ can be solved to obtain a running time of $\Theta(n \log{n})$. This is evident from the form of the algorithm, assuming the complexity of the details is easy enough to determine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FFT complexity is usually given in terms of number of multiplications ($mul$) and additions ($add$).

## General formula

That's correct $$O(N^2 \times mul + N^2 \times add)$$

## Cooley-Tukey

First remember the algorithm:
$$X_k = E_k + t_k O_k, k \le \frac N 2$$
$$X_k = E_{k-\frac N 2} - t_{k-\frac N 2}O_{k-\frac N 2}, k > \frac N 2$$
where $E$ is DFT of the even indexed samples, $O$ DFT of the odd indexed samples, and $t$ is the twiddle factor.

We also know that $N = 2^L,L\ge 0$

The number of operations to compute $X$ of size $N=2^L$ if $E,O,t$ are known is:
$$2^{L-1} \times mul + 2^{L} \times add$$
To compute the $E$ and $O$ we need to do the computation twice but of size $2^{L-1}$ and so on. For a $i \le L$ we have to do the computation $2^{L-i}$ times.

Putting this together the total complexity is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{L}2^{L-i}O(2^{i-1} \times mul + 2^{i} \times add) = \sum_{i=1}^{L}O(2^{L-1} \times mul + 2^{L} \times add) = O(L\cdot 2^{L-1} \times mul + L \cdot 2^{L} \times add) = O(log(N)\frac N 2 \times mul + log(N)N\times add)$$

## Bluestein's algorithm

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this algorithm

## Prime-factor algorithm

$$N = N_1\cdot N_2$$
where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are relatively prime.

Notice that the algorithm is essentially DFT applied twice.  The inner sum is DFT of size $N_1$ that has to be calculated for each $n_2$ (i.e. $N_2$ times).  The outer sum is DFT of size $N_2$ calculated $N_1$ times.  The complexity thus is:

$$O(N_2\cdot O(DFT_{N_1}) + N_1 \cdot O(DFT_{N_2})) = O(N_2\cdot N_1^2\times (mul + add) + N_1 \cdot N_2^2\times (mul + add)) = O(N\cdot (N_1+N_2)\times (mul + add)) $$

For trivial factorization $N_1=N,N_2=1$, the complexity is $O(N^2)$, but for $N_1$ and $N_2$ of similar size, this is close to $O(N \sqrt N)$.